# Angular 5 HTTP.get returns cannot read length of undefined

Tags: angular, rxjs, httpresponse, ngrx

This call is being made from my service to retrieve a URL to download a document:

```
return this.http.get(this.buildUrl('issueDocument', 'get', pathParams), { responseType: 'blob', params: queryParams });
```

The buildURL inside this.http.get is working properly I've tested it however, the return for this.http.get throws this error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at HttpHeaders.applyUpdate (http.js:322)
    at eval (http.js:269)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HttpHeaders.init (http.js:269)
    at HttpHeaders.forEach (http.js:368)
    at Observable.eval [as _subscribe] (http.js:2172)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:172)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:160)
    at CatchOperator.call (catchError.js:80)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:157)
```

Any ideas on what's going on? I can't fit together why this is happening... In the dev tools network tab it's not even showing a network call...

Comment: Seems like a bad header. Does your app use HTTP interceptors or something like that?

Comment: what do you mean by bad header?

Comment: A header whose value would be `undefined`, according to the error message.

Comment: Nope I do have an interceptor service but I've also broken this line down serveral times. There are no undefined values.

Comment: Post that interceptor's code then if you can. I don't think the error comes from that line you posted.

Comment: Hey, yeah I figured out the issue it was with the interceptor. It wasn't properly dealing with the URL. Thanks a bunch~!

Answer (score 1):

From the error message it appears you just need to not let `undefined` passed into your `.set(...)` of the headers.

I do this:

```
 getHeaders() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .set('Authorization', localStorage.getItem('token') || '');
    return headers;
  }
```

Comment: That can work but it has to receive a response. Turns out that the API I was provided was responding correctly but that particular response was lacking the correct permissions...

Answer (score 0):

to fix this, check variable before setting into header

```
if (!headers.has("Content-Type"))
    { headers = headers.clone( { headers: headers.set("Content-Type",  "application/json") }); }
```